# Android Development End of Life an application

Tags: android

I am currently writing a application that will eventually be going to market, but for now it will be in the Alpha stage.  I am trying to come up with the best way to "time bomb" the application, so if it is ran after a certain date it will prompt the user saying the alpha application is expired and close.

I will not be doing this to an application in the market, the reason I want to do this is that I will be passing out this application to a few friends and want to make sure they will not be running older version of the software.

I know that if you self-sign the application, you can sign it with a date and it can't be installed after said date, but if it is already installed it still can be ran.

Any suggestions on how to neatly do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just call the Date.after(Date) function, and if you are past the date of expiration, post something that says this version can't be used any more. Just do it in your main function before doing anything useful, and you should be set.

Comment: I knew there would be an easy way to do this, thanks very much.