# Get Android system permissions by putting app in /system/app?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

Experimenting with some newer Android APIs from the AOSP, I have found some that require the android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED permission.  According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED), the permission "is not available to third party applications."

I have read elsewhere that you can get system level permissions on a rooted device by installing your app in the /system/app directory.  I have tried this on my rooted Nexus 5, but my app still does not get the desired privilege. (See code and LogCat output below.)

[An alternative I have heard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731004/how-to-grant-system-permissions-to-my-android-app) is to build your own custom Android ROM, then sign the app with the same key.  I could do this, but would strongly prefer to be able to use a stock image if it is possible.

So which is it?  Is it possible to get system level permissions on a rooted phone with a stock image?  If so, am I doing something wrong?

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if ((this.getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "This is a system application");
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "This is not a system application");         
    }
    if (getApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d(TAG, "I have android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED");
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "I do not have android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED");            
    }       
    ...     

}
```

LogCat output:

```
W/PackageManager(  788): Not granting permission android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED to package com.radiusnetworks.testapp (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be47)
I/ActivityManager(  788): Start proc com.radiusnetworks.testapp for activity com.radiusnetworks.testapp/.MainActivity: pid=3124 uid=10075 gids={50075, 3002, 3001}
D/MainActivity( 3124): This is a system application
D/MainActivity( 3124): I do not have android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.radiusnetworks.testapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> 
  <uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"/>    
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />     

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.radiusnetworks.testapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of Android 4.4, Privileged Apps must be put in /system/priv-app instead of /system/app.  Once I moved my app there, it got the privilege as expected.

See here: [AOSP Privileged vs System app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868138/aosp-privileged-vs-system-app)

Comment: How can I install my app in the /system/app or /system/priv-app directory on a rooted device? Is it just moving the apk file from /data/app folder after installing?

Comment: Yes, it's just that simple!

Comment: I saw someone calling `adb` commands `remount` and `push`. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

For apps within the `/priv-apps/` directory to use higher permissions they must be signed with the same keys the OS was signed with.

Answer (score 0):

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-allowlist <--- you can apparently build n have the android push your own  configed lriv app lermissjon list then it will auto add the apk to the  phones system along with their default whitelisted apks.. u even have option - a to literally add every apk on phone lol.. perfect after i researchd n compiled because i obtained root but dont have su or nothin so before i found this it was always a pain to try n dk crap because i had diff privs n diff apks n it got confusing lol.. not anymore >=) look at this page youll read see a link o get to the project and even further instructions.. =)

Comment: Welcome Timothy. Please avoid weird abbreviation, symbol or similar thing in your post and care about the grammar.