# How to receive input events in TvInputService overlay view

Tags: android-tv

[Tv Input Framework (TIF) documentaition](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/#mheg-5_input_example) says:

> Only system TV Inputs are eligible to receive `InputEvents`, and only if they have the `RECEIVE_INPUT_EVENT` system permission. The TV Input is responsible to determine which `InputEvent`s to consume and should allow the TV App to handle the keys it does not need to consume.

This `RECEIVE_INPUT_EVENT` seems to be a system permission.
Trying to enable it via `adb` fails:

```
$ adb shell pm grant com.example.mytvinput \
  com.android.tv.permission.RECEIVE_INPUT_EVENT

Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission 
com.android.tv.permission.RECEIVE_INPUT_EVENT is not a changeable permission type
```

[Android Open Source Project (AOSP) sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/TV/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml#47) indicate that `RECEIVE_INPUT_EVENT` permission is `signatureOrSystem` type, which in turn is defined by [Android Permission documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html) as:

> A permission that the system grants only to applications that are in the Android system image or that are signed with the same certificate as the application that declared the permission.

How to develop an overlay to Android Tv Input Service that is consuming input (e.g. HbbTv)?

Do I have to compile the developed Tv Input into an android image in order to develop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install your application in `/system/priv-app`.

`/system/priv-app` is a special place for applications wanting more permissions than others .

### Step-by-step

To start an emulator with writable system partition, you should use `-writable-system` flag.

```
./emulator -writable-system -avd Oreo_Android_TV_1080p_API_26
```

Next remount `/system` partition with

```
adb root
adb remount
```

Next move your application to `/system/priv-app` and reboot

```
adb shell mv /data/app/com.example.myinput /system/priv-app/com.example.myinput
```

### Sources

[Android Emulator Command Line doc, explaining -writable-service flag](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html)

[What is the difference between system apps and privileged apps on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296286/get-android-system-permissions-by-putting-app-in-system-app)