# Read sensor info with AndroidX in Android Automotive OS - not able to add permission

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-permissions, android-automotive

I am trying to read information from an AVD running Android Automotive OS 13.
I am using AndroidX and attempting to access the vehicle's speed.
A minimal example that does not work:

```
AutomotiveCarHardwareManager(context).carInfo.addSpeedListener(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) {}
```

It requires a permission to work:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.SecurityException: Missed permission: android.car.permission.CAR_SPEED
```

When I add this permission to `AndroidManifest.xml` it does not change anything (same error output with/without). Note: The manifest is 'set up' correctly and does work with other general permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.car.permission.CAR_INFO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.car.permission.CAR_SPEED"/>
```

I am not able to import `android.car.permission.CAR_SPEED` in my main code and following the sources in the error, those files appear to have many import errors too.

Is there a possibility that I need a custom build or something like that in order to access privileged information such as vehicle speed?

Thank you!

---

Full exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.autodemo, PID: 11953
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.SecurityException: Missed permission: android.car.permission.CAR_SPEED
at androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils.lambda$dispatchCallFromHost$0(RemoteUtils.java:155)
at androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:6)
at androidx.car.app.utils.ThreadUtils.runOnMain(ThreadUtils.java:39)
at androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils.dispatchCallFromHost(RemoteUtils.java:147)
at androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils.lambda$dispatchCallFromHost$1(RemoteUtils.java:186)
at androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:8)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7924)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Missed permission: android.car.permission.CAR_SPEED
at androidx.car.app.hardware.common.PropertyManager.checkPermissions(PropertyManager.java:310)
at androidx.car.app.hardware.common.PropertyManager.submitRegisterListenerRequest(PropertyManager.java:105)
at androidx.car.app.hardware.info.AutomotiveCarInfo.addSpeedListener(AutomotiveCarInfo.java:188)
at com.example.autodemo.InfoScreen.onGetTemplate(InfoScreen.kt:69)
at androidx.car.app.Screen.getTemplateWrapper(Screen.java:361)
at androidx.car.app.ScreenManager.getTopTemplate(ScreenManager.java:279)
at androidx.car.app.AppManager$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.dispatch(Unknown Source:2)
at androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils.lambda$dispatchCallFromHost$0(RemoteUtils.java:150)
at androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:6)
at androidx.car.app.utils.ThreadUtils.runOnMain(ThreadUtils.java:39)
at androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils.dispatchCallFromHost(RemoteUtils.java:147)
at androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils.lambda$dispatchCallFromHost$1(RemoteUtils.java:186)
at androidx.car.app.utils.RemoteUtils$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:8)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7924)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Comment: If you need this permission , the application that uses it must be signed by system. Also you can try to put your app in another folder.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296286/get-android-system-permissions-by-putting-app-in-system-app

Comment: Aha thanks a lot. Since I am just using an AVD for the moment, not a physical Android device, my route is to create a new signing config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[android.car.permission.CAR_SPEED](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:cts/tests/tests/permission2/res/raw/automotive_android_manifest.xml;l=87?q=android.car.permission.CAR_SPEED) is dangerous runtime permission. Did you [request runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) properly?

[android.car.permission.CAR_INFO](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:cts/tests/tests/permission2/res/raw/automotive_android_manifest.xml;l=128?q=android.car.permission.CAR_SPEED) is normal permission, so declare it's usage in manifest should be enough.

Comment: Note: For my version `carContext.requestPermissions(listOf("android.car.permission.CAR_SPEED")) { grantedPermissions, rejectedPermissions -> whatever}` seems to have worked